# How to submit a form with JavaScript that has been dynamically created?

Tags: javascript, forms, hyperlink, form-submit

I am trying to submit a form with JavaScript without a submit button and using a text link. However, this form is dynamically created in PHP as follows:

```
   <form action="profile.php" method="POST" id="searchResultProfileView1" enctype="multipart/form-data">

   <div class="searchResultsFriendInfo">

     <p><img  class="searchResultsFriendImage" src="<?php print $row['ppPath'] ?>" alt="" ></p>

     <p class="searchResultsFriendName"><a class="tabLinks" href="" id="linkToProfile1"><?=ucwords($row["firstname"])?> <?=ucwords($row["lastname"])?></a></p>

     <input type="hidden" name="user_Id" value="<?php print $row["id"] ?>">             

     <p><input type="button" class="searchResultsConnect" value="Connect"></p>

     </div>

    </form>
```

and my JavaScript code is as follows

```
 document.observe("dom:loaded", function()
 {
  $("linkToProfile1").onclick=submitForm;

 });

 function submitForm()
 {
   $("searchResultProfileView1").submit(); 
 }
```

But when I try to do so the JavaScript it gives me an error:

```
searchResultProfileOpen.js:3Uncaught TypeError: Cannot set property 'onclick' of null
```

Again this form was dynamically created so I am assuming JavaScript events cannot properly listen to dom object that are dynamically created with PHP.

Answer (score 1):

If you're dynamically creating the form why not try to specifying the `onClick` in the code for the href.

```
<a onClick="submitForm();" class="tabLinks" href="" id="linkToProfile1"><?=ucwords($row["firstname"])?> <?=ucwords($row["lastname"])?></a>
```

This way you can remove the `document.observe()`.

Answer (score 0):

You're not dynamically creating the form.  at least not according to javascript.  why don't you try viewing the source on your web page and figure out why the form is null.  probably a php error writing the html

Answer (score 0):

It should be `$("#linkToProfile1").onclick=submitForm;` and `$("#searchResultProfileView1").submit();`, isn't it?